# MySQL Workbench can not start

Tags: c++, mysql, windows-7

I have `Win7 (x64)`, installed `Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2` and `Visual C++ Redistributable` for `Visual Studio 2013` but my `MySQL Workbench` can not get running. When I try to open it, it doesn't display any error message or anything else. It just doesnt want to start.

I also searched for help and some people recommend to delete folder in `C://Users/*****/AppData/Roaming/MySQL/Workbench` and I did, but nothing's changed.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: you can probably download [mysql-connector-net-6.9.7.msi](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=458797) which acutally works great with me

Comment: Installed it, restarted computer, MySQL WorkBench still dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install x32 version and now everything works fine, which is really odd because my Win7 is x64, but problem solved.